# surfaceCreated() not called on loading of a customized SurfaceView inside a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, surfaceview, horizontalscrollview, textureview

I am trying to embed a customized `SurfaceView` inside a `HorizontalScrollView`. I have set up everything correctly but I don't get a callback to my `surfaceCreated()` which is implemented as a part of `SurfaceHolder.Callback` interface. The part of the layout xml is:

```
..........
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizScroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">

            <com.purandara.views.PitchSurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/pitchView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lesson_page_title_bar_height"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/lesson_page_ctrl_bar_height"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
..............
```

I came across this [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/android-40-graphics-and-animations.html) article which sayas that it is **difficult to use a SurfaceView inside a ListView or a ScrollView**. But, does it mean that I cannot even create a customized `SurfaceView` inside a `HorizontalScrollView`? What I understand from this is that, since a `SurfaceView` does not live in the *application window*, it cannot be mentioned in the xml which is the layout for the entire activity and has other components as well. Rather, we can inflate a layout containing only a `SurfaceView` and then attach it to the layout of our activity.

As mentioned in the blog article, I tried using `TextureView` and I am successfully getting a callback to the `onSurfaceTextureAvailable()` method implemented as a part of `TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener` interface.

Please let me know if there is some error in my understanding.

Edit 1:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_evaluation);
....................
```

In my onCreate() method, I have set the content view as mentioned above where the the `activity_evaluation` is a `FrameLayout`containing the `HorizontalScrollView` as an immediate child.

In the constructor of my custom view, I get the handle of the `SurfaceHolder` and then setting the listener for the SurfaceHolder.CallBack by

```
mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
```

which I guess is a very standard way of doing this. After doing this, when I load my activity, I see a black colored blank screen where my customized `SurfaceView` is supposed to show and I do not get a callback on my `surfaceCreated()` method. Let me know if you need more information on this.
Thanks.

Comment: SurfaceView doesn't scroll well because the View part and the Surface part are independent. When the View moves, it has to send an IPC request to the window manager to move the Surface, which means the movement lags behind by a couple of frames. Since you have TextureView working, you should probably stick with that. Not sure why the callback isn't firing; you'd need to show some code (e.g. onCreate()) if you want to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I have added some code and explanation for my implementation.